# How to change color of a textArea at runtime?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I am using a TextArea in my application, and wish to change the font color of textArea at runtime based on certain conditions? I am using the following code in a function

resultText.setStyle("color", 0x842D22).
However, this does not work, and gives me an exception at runtime
Cannot Access property of null object reference.

setStyle does not seem to work with textArea . please advise.

Comment: Can you set other properties of the resultText object using the setStyle method? The null object reference might indicate that resultText is null when you try to use it. Maybe you could post a bigger snippet of the method you are having problems with.

Answer (score 2):

See if this example helps you:

> ```
>  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
>    <mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute">
> <mx:Script>
>     <![CDATA[
>         public var flag:Boolean = true;
>         public function clickHandler():void{
>          if(flag)
>           {resultText.setStyle("color","red");
>            }
>            else
>            {
>            resultText.setStyle("color","blue");
>            }    
>           flag = !flag;
>         }
>         ]]>
> </mx:Script><mx:TextArea x="59" y="104" id="resultText"/>
> <mx:Button id="colorChangeButton" label="Change Color" click="clickHandler()" x="83" y="180" /></mx:Application>
> ```

Try sharing code in case  this doesnt help..

Comment: This solution only changes the text color.  Set style on backgroundColor instead.

Comment: @adam codes..The question asked was to set font color.Anyway it doesnt matter what attribute is being set.Since the exception is 'null object reference', the resultText instance is null somehow when setStyle is being done.

Comment: You are correct -- I don't know why I thought bgcolor. Sorry.